# Calling class functions from class functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class

I hate that I'm doing this but I've just started working with Javascript classes and I can't figure out how to call member functions from member functions.  Below is the class I have and when I run this I get the following error in Firefox:

> this.addCol is not a function

I've also tried calling the function like this:

```
Table.prototype.addCol(this,key,value);
```

but that also didn't work.  :-)

```
Table.prototype.addCol = function(key, values){
    this.jquery.children('.columns').append('<li>' + key + '</li>');
}

Table.prototype.setData = function(data){
    // store the data for this table
    this.data = data;

    $.each(data.columns, function(key, value){
        this.addCol(key, value);
    });
}

function Table (name){
    this.name = name;

    this.jquery = $('<div class="dbtable"><h3>' + this.name + '</h3></div>');
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that `this` doesn't refer to your `Table` object inside of that anonymous function. Use a normal for-loop and it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript has prototypal inheritance, not classical inheritance. There are no "classes" in JS. Using the "new Foo()" syntax in JS just sucks. It wasn't built to support that style of coding well.

That being said, there is a major design flaw in which a nested function inside an object will rebind `this` to the global object. In this case, `this` gets re-bound to the item in the `$.each` iteration.

There is a common workaround:

```
Table.prototype.setData = function(data){
    var that = this;
    // store the data for this table
    this.data = data;

    $.each(data.columns, function(key, value){
        that.addCol(key, value);
    });
}
```

Comment: Modifications to `addCol`?  This change wouldn't fix the error message `this.addCol is not a function`

Comment: It's not a design flaw, that's how free functions work. In this case, it's also not JS that's setting the binding, it's [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), which binds `this` to the elements of the collection being traversed (after wrapping primitive types in Objects). In any case, this solution is the simplest.

Comment: This is more of a problem of functional scope. :P

Comment: Douglas Crockford would disagree with you about the design flaw part, though he is a pretty harsh critic ;)

Comment: @AlienWebguy This works but I don't understand why (and I hate saying that).  Can you point my in the direction of something that would explain this (I would even be willing to pay for a physical book :-)).

Comment: Using `this` inside the `$.each` method sets the scope of `this` to the `each` function. Therefore `this` refers to the value currently being iterated through, not the `Table Class`.  To get around this, AlienWebguy set a variable called `that` outside of the `$.each` method. Javascript is a functional language which is why the context  gets changed as such.

Comment: Sure, check out [JavaScript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1327542772&sr=8-1). The reason is because `this.addCol()` really didn't exist. `this.data` worked because `this` pointed to `Table`. Once inside that `$.each(`function, `this` no longer pointed to Table but rather the current item in the iteration. Since you didn't create an `addCol()` function property to that item, it didn't exist. `var that = this` just creates a variable pointing to Table which we reference inside `$.each`

Answer (score 0):

Why not define the class as

```
function Table (name){
    this.name = name;

    this.jquery = $('<div class="dbtable"><h3>' + this.name + '</h3></div>');

    this.addCol = function(key, values){
        this.jquery.children('.columns').append('<li>' + key + '</li>');
    }

    this.setData = function(data){
        // store the data for this table
        this.data = data;

        $.each(data.columns, function(key, value){
            this.addCol(key, value);
        });
    }
}
```

in the first place?

Comment: For one reason, it's more memory intensive to instantiate new objects from this constructor.

Comment: I would argue that getting the application to work should be priority #1, and then optimization can come second.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin True, but he has already written it that way, plus the problem is `this` pointing to the global object, not what you have described.